# Trouble creating my own bubble sort method for an Array class

Tags: arrays, ruby, bubble-sort, spaceship-operator

I completely understand how a bubble sort works. It's just I have been given a coding exercise where I have to create a method that's monkey patched to the Array class where a block of code is used and it has the spaceship operator. Below is my code:

```
class Array
  def bubble_sort!
    len = self.length - 1

    loop do
      swapped = false

      for i in 0...len 
        if self[i] > self[i + 1]
          self[i], self[i + 1] = self[i + 1], self[i]
          swapped = true
        end 
      end

      break if swapped == false
    end

    self
  end

  # def bubble_sort(&prc)
  # end
end
```

This is my `bubble_sort!` method but I have no idea how to write this with a 'spaceship operrator' `<=>` being used inside a block. The exercise wants me to be able to pass a block `{|num1,num2| num1 <=> num2}` ascending order and `{|num1,num2| num2 <=> num1}` descending order into the method. I have no problem calling a block and I do understand how the spaceship operator compares its variable `< == -1`, `= == 0` and `> == 1`. My only problem is I don't know how to write that into an actual conditional statement for the bubble sort.

Comment: How come is this question related to Ruby on Rails? I think the tag is wrong. Just ruby is fine here!

Comment: Editing tags rn.

Comment: The block for a sorting method is generally used to compare two elements to determine what order they should go in. So where is your bubble sort comparing things? And maybe look at [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Comparable.html) for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

The line in your code that is comparing elements is this one:

```
if self[i] > self[i + 1]
```

With this logic, you swap if the first element is higher than the second, meaning your result will be sorted in ascending order.

You can replace it as follows:

```
if prc.call(self[i], self[i + 1]) == 1
```

and then call the method like so:

```
print [5,1,4,2,3].bubble_sort! { |a,b| a <=> b }
# => [1,2,3,4,5]

print [5,1,4,2,3].bubble_sort! { |a,b| b <=> a }
# => [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following:

```
# ....
for i in 0...len
  condition =
    if block_given?
      yield(self[i], self[i + 1]).positive?
    else
      self[i] > self[i + 1]
    end

  if condition
    self[i], self[i + 1] = self[i + 1], self[i]
    swapped = true
  end
end
# ....


# Usage:
my_array.bubble_sort!
my_array.bubble_sort! { |num1, num2| num1 <=> num2 }
```

Comment: That sounds promising but now we come to the issue where if we wanted to get it in ascending order.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Could you please explain more clearly